# Override compodoc template

Tags: handlebars.js, compodoc

Hello I am using [compodoc](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc) 1.1.5 to generate the documentation for my angular project. Compodoc provides the ability to override the template by using the option `--template  folder_name`. I tried to override the menu partial by creating a partial folder and putting a menu.hbs in it with the code from the original menu.hbs (the menu disappeared completely) even if I do not modify the original code. I am getting this error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token     menu-wc.js:34`

Does any one have any idea about the proper way to override templates

Answer (score 0):

Either create your own theme or create an additional doc folder.

The additional docs folder will accept `.md` and `.html` files.

See https://compodoc.app/guides/usage.html for more.